How to add a subscript with other characters in the title using ggplot in R?
I want the graph's title to show "the title is m0", in which 0 is placed as a subscript next to "m". I am using the expression() but it works without other characters, while fail to make it a subscript when other characters are present. How can we fix this?
data("iris")

ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    labs(title = paste0("the title is ", expression(m[0])))

The resulting graph looks like

See that the title does not give what I want by displaying [0] rather than 0 (subscript).

Use paste rather than paste0 and change the calls to expression and paste like so.
data("iris")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = expression(paste('The title is ', m[0])))


I'm not sure why paste0 doesn't work.

What if I want to add another variable i, which depends on varying values (i = 1, 2, ... ) in the title? It seems like labs(title = expression(paste('The title is ', m[0], i))) can't print the value of i

ggplot(data=iris,mapping=aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  labs(title = "the title is m<sub>0</sub>") +
  theme(title = ggtext::element_markdown())


